# Create dataframe from 2 other dataframes using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Create a new dataframe from 2 other dataframes using python

I have two dataframes with the same column names (df_a and df_b) and I need to create a new dataframe in Python.

df_a

| cod_anuncio | score |
| --- | --- |
| 460 | 1.000000 |
| 239 | 0.999992 |
| 422 | 0.999984 |
| 231 | 0.999966 |
| 455 | 0.999956 |
| 238 | 0.999953 |
| 426 | 0.999951 |
| 281 | 0.999940 |
| 465 | 0.999936 |
| 230 | 0.999935 |
| 427 | 0.999931 |
| 188 | 0.999928 |

df_b

| cod_anuncio | score |
| --- | --- |
| 488 | 0.999986 |
| 234 | 0.999923 |
| 779 | 0.999913 |
| 224 | 0.999900 |
| 460 | 0.999900 |
| 239 | 0.999874 |
| 422 | 0.999872 |
| 231 | 0.999870 |
| 455 | 0.999868 |
| 238 | 0.999866 |
| 426 | 0.999862 |
| 281 | 0.999860 |
| 465 | 0.999850 |
| 230 | 0.999844 |
| 427 | 0.999837 |
| 188 | 0.999815 |

The score column is in descending order in both dataframes (df_a and df_b)

`df_a.shape[0] = 400`
`df_b.shape[0] = 300`

I need a function that creates a new dataframe. For each set of 10 rows, you need to get the first 7 rows from df_a and 3 rows from df_b (with the highest score).

Explaining again to help understand: in each block of 10 lines to take 7 rows from df_a and 3 from df_b

Remember that you need to have a function with for to contemplate all rows from df_a and df_b.

I need something like this dataframe:

df

| cod_anuncio | score |
| --- | --- |
| 460 | 1.000000 |
| 239 | 0.999992 |
| 488 | 0.999986 |
| 422 | 0.999984 |
| 231 | 0.999966 |
| 455 | 0.999956 |
| 238 | 0.999953 |
| 426 | 0.999951 |
| 234 | 0.999923 |
| 779 | 0.999913 |

`df.shape[0] = 700`

With this code I ordered the first then rows:

`pd.concat([df_a.iloc[0:7], df_b.iloc[0:3]], axis=0, ignore_index=False).sort_values(['score'], ascending=[False])`

But, bow, I need help to order the ads, but I'm prioritizing the ads from df_a, so I need to put 70% of them in front.

I really need help on this issue. thank you very much.

Comment: Your description and the example don't match. Also if the shapes are 400 and 300 and the output 700 there is no selection of rows, you just concatenate everything

Comment: For dfa, 400 is not divisible by 7, 399 is. It will remain one row alone from dfa.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, create a key for each dataframe to sort the output:

```
out = (pd.concat([dfa.assign(grp=np.arange(len(dfa)) // 7),
                  dfb.assign(grp=np.arange(len(dfb)) // 3)],
                 keys=['dfa', 'dfb'], names=['df']).reset_index('df')
         .sort_values(['grp', 'score'], ascending=[True, False]))
```

Output:

```
>>> out.head(30)
     df  cod_anuncio     score  grp
0   dfa         1400  1.000000    0
0   dfb         1300  1.000000    0
1   dfa         1399  0.997494    0
1   dfb         1299  0.996656    0
2   dfa         1398  0.994987    0
2   dfb         1298  0.993311    0
3   dfa         1397  0.992481    0
4   dfa         1396  0.989975    0
5   dfa         1395  0.987469    0
6   dfa         1394  0.984962    0

3   dfb         1297  0.989967    1
4   dfb         1296  0.986622    1
5   dfb         1295  0.983278    1
7   dfa         1393  0.982456    1
8   dfa         1392  0.979950    1
9   dfa         1391  0.977444    1
10  dfa         1390  0.974937    1
11  dfa         1389  0.972431    1
12  dfa         1388  0.969925    1
13  dfa         1387  0.967419    1

6   dfb         1294  0.979933    2
7   dfb         1293  0.976589    2
8   dfb         1292  0.973244    2
14  dfa         1386  0.964912    2
15  dfa         1385  0.962406    2
16  dfa         1384  0.959900    2
17  dfa         1383  0.957393    2
18  dfa         1382  0.954887    2
19  dfa         1381  0.952381    2
20  dfa         1380  0.949875    2
```

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
dfa = (pd.DataFrame({'cod_anuncio': np.arange(1000, 1400),
                     'score': rng.uniform(0, 1, 400)})
         .sort_values('score', ascending=False, ignore_index=True))
dfb = (pd.DataFrame({'cod_anuncio': np.arange(1000, 1300),
                     'score': rng.uniform(0, 1, 300)})
         .sort_values('score', ascending=False, ignore_))
```

Comment: @vivi_program. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Creating 2 data frames as stated in the requirements

    df_a = pd.DataFrame({'cod_anuncio':np.random.randint(0,500, size=400),
    'score': sorted((np.random.uniform(0,1) for _ in range(400)),reverse=True)})
    df_b = pd.DataFrame({'cod_anuncio':np.random.randint(0,500, size=300),
    'score': sorted((np.random.uniform(0,1) for _ in range(300)),reverse=True)})

    print(df_a.shape, df_b.shape)

    df_set = list()
    j = 0
    i = 0
    while i <= df_a.shape[0]: #since with 7 records taken from df_a it will exhaust earlier
        i_=i+7
        j_=j+3
        df_set.append(df_a.iloc[i:i_,:].append(df_b.iloc[j:j_,:]).sort_values(by ='score', ascending=False))
        i=i_
        j=j_
    
    remaining_df_a = df_a.iloc[i-7:,:]
    remaining_df_b = df_b.iloc[j-3:,:]
    
    print(remaining_df_a.shape, remaining_df_b.shape) #you may choose to append this to final new_df below
    
    new_df = pd.concat(df_set,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
```

Sample output:

```
    new_df.head(30)


        cod_anuncio     score
0           334  0.999084
1           288  0.997893
2           263  0.996936
3           457  0.996754
4           371  0.996379
5           436  0.987302
6           113  0.986023
7           386  0.985644
8           394  0.985083
9           269  0.984212
10           70  0.994140
11           93  0.991378
12          411  0.987958
13          276  0.982341
14          475  0.980935
15            0  0.977755
16          357  0.973407
17          305  0.973180
18          455  0.970570
19          425  0.969787
20          499  0.987544
21            6  0.986837
22          302  0.984846
23          477  0.969554
24          202  0.969076
25          359  0.967893
26          103  0.965974
27          486  0.965834
28          238  0.964018
29          384  0.959579
```